# Mock3Aggregator.sol refuses to compile

Tags: solidity, hardhat, error, bug

I am currently working on deploying a contract in my local hardhat network, the files below:

1. MockV3Aggregator.sol - the smart contract

```
    pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
    
    import "@chainink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockAggregator.sol"
```

2. The 00-deploy-mocks.js --- the file responsible for deploying the smart contract

```
  const {
      developmentChain,
      DECIMALS,
      INITIAL_ANSWER,
  } = require("../helper-hardhat.config")
  
  module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
      const { deploy, log } = deployments
      const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
  
      if (developmentChain.includes(network.name)) {
          log("Local Network detected! Deploying mocks... ")
          await deploy("MockV3Aggregator ", {
              contract: "MockV3Aggregator",
              from: deployer,
              log: true,
              args: [DECIMALS, INITIAL_ANSWER],
          })
          log("Mocks Deployed...")
          log("_________________________________________")
      }
  }
```

and my hardhat-config.js

```
 require("hardhat-deploy")
 
 /** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
 module.exports = {
     // solidity: "0.8.8",
     solidity: {
         compilers: [{ version: "0.8.8" }, { version: "0.6.0" }],
     },
     networks: {
         sepolia: {
             url: process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL || "",
             accounts: [],
         },
     },
     gasReporter: {
         enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS != undefined,
         currency: "USD",
     },
     etherscan: {
         apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
     },
     namedAccounts: {
         deployer: {
             default: 0,
         },
     },
 }
```

It keep giving this error in my terminal when i run the code below in my terminal:

```
Nothing to compile
Local Network detected! Deploying mocks... 
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing /Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:
Error: cannot find artifact "MockV3Aggregator"
    at getArtifact (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:207:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at getArtifactFromOptions (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:502:20)
    at getLinkedArtifact (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:518:38)
    at _deploy (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:539:54)
    at _deployOne (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:1014:16)
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:14:9)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1055:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1225:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1055:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/mac/Documents/Codes/blockchain-projects/Hardhat-FundMe/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:669:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive this should fix your error...

use:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `contracts\test\MockV3Aggregator.sol`
Make sure to have `import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";`